# Failling saves after introducing a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've encountered a problem in my Railsapp after I introduced a polymorphic association. The app consists of teams (along other models) that can have multiple attributes. So I followed the railscasts episode and came up with this:

app/models/attribute.rb

```
class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :attributable, polymorphic: true
end
```

app/models/team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attributes, as: :attributable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attributes
end
```

After doing so I encountered this in an IRB Session:

```
irb(main):001:0> t = Team.new(name: "Test")
=> #<Team id: nil, name: "Test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, scopes_mask: nil>
irb(main):002:0> t.save
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
            commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):003:0> t.save
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
            rollback transaction
NoMethodError:   Attribute Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "attributes".* FROM "attributes" WHERE "attributes"."attributable_id" = 1 AND "attributes"."attributable_type" = 'Team'
undefined method `keys' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

So the error just happens on previously recorded records. Building records and attributes befor the first save works perfectly fine, as does loading of records.

I hope for any help on the situation.
Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

[`attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) is a method already which is part of ActiveRecord. I strongly suspect that naming your association `attributes` as well is causing the problem. If you name it differently to avoid the conflict with ActiveRecord internals it should work fine.